# Postgresql сломалась репликация

Tags: postgresql

Почистил я однажды базу основательно так, н апару миллионов записей. после чего  slave  рассинхронизировался с мастером. заглянул в логи, а там
requested WAL segment has already been removed

путём гугления понял что надо бы стянуть с мастера базу заново. сделал  pg_basebackup -h ip -D /db -P -U rep , но ничего не изменилось. Что я делаю не так?
Postgresql 10,  репликации потоковые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы потоковой репликации необходимо откуда-то получить непрерывную последовательность WAL. Если база с которой вы настроили получение WAL уже удалила сегмент - то тут как раз репликация и встанет с ошибкой, что такого сегмента уже нет. Если его восстановить неоткуда - то необходимо копировать реплику заново. Наиболее простой способ - через `pg_basebackup`, вы всё верно нашли.

Однако требование к непрерывности WAL сохраняется. Как раз начиная с релиза postgresql 10 pg_basebackup загружает все WAL от начала и до конца выполнения pg_basebackup по-умолчанию. Но между окончанием pg_basebackup и до запуска walreceiver (процесса, который загружает WAL с другого сервера) есть разница во времени, в течении которой необходимые для новой реплики WAL могут быть вновь удалены. И придётся копировать базу ещё раз.

Что с этим можно сделать настройками:

- использовать [`replication slots`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS). Эта хорошая по своей идее штука будет гарантировать, что база не удалит WAL, пока реплика использующая этот слот репликации не подтвердит что скопировала этот WAL. Но критично важно настроить мониторинг слотов репликации. Если вы случайно оставите слот и его никто не будет читать - ваша директория `pg_wal` будет расти без какого-либо ограничения до аварийной остановки базы.
- указать некоторый `wal_keep_segments` - это количество файлов WAL сервер будет хранить сверх необходимого для своей работы. Это повысит требуемое дисковое место на постоянную величину пропорциональную этой настройке, однако проблемы связи с репликами не приведут к остановке работы этой базы. Таким образом у вас будет фиксированный объём отставания реплик, который те смогут наверстать.